# Strange behavior of mv/cp for directory "." on Linux

Tags: command-line, unix

I note a strange behavior of mv/cp on Linux. The directories A and A/. should be equivalent but as arguments for the source they seem to behave differently. Is that a bug?
Of course you could ask why should I use A/. instead of A as source but sometimes one wants "." as source and the same strange things happen... Maybe someone knows an answer.

Let's start with

```
$ mkdir A A/A1 B
```

and now

variant 1)

```
$ cp -r A B
$ ls B
A
```

All right.

variant 2)

```
$ cp -r A/. B
$ ls B
A1
```

Why "A1" and not "A"?

variant 3)

```
$ mv A B
$ ls B
A
```

All right.

variant 4)

```
$ mv -i A/. B
mv: overwrite `B/.'? y
mv: cannot move `A/.' to `B/.': Device or resource busy
```

strange...

Comment: @SachinDivekar You have `mkdir -p` aliased.

Comment: @DanielBeck sorry my bad. forgot `-p`

Comment: on the other note, no need to mkdir A A/A1 B you can just do `mkdir -p A/A1 B` it will create A and A/A1 automatically.

Answer (score 2):

"A" and "A/." are both directory entries that point to the same thing, but they are themselves different things.  "A" is an entry in the current directory, and "A/." is an entry named "." in the A directory.  Think of it as operating on a box from the outside, vs. operating on the box from the inside.

Specifically,

> cp -r A B

Copies A into B.

> cp -r A/. B

Goes into the directory A and copies the contents of the current directory (i.e. ./A1) into B.

> mv A B

Moves the directory entry named "A" from the current directory into B.

> mv -i A/. B

Tries to move the directory entry "." out of A into B.  However, there's already an entry named "." in B.  In general, you can't move "." (that's like trying to move the box from the inside).